# How is the proper way to use class members in another class?

Tags: c++, class, public

I am trying to use class members from a different class adding the "**class uart**" to "**class parser : public uart**"

But I can't use members variables in parser class for example (bufer_size, buffer, or state Enum the values are not changing or updating) the only way I can use these variables are using them as external variables, but I would like do it in a class member way.

Below please find my code:

**main:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parser.h"
int main()
{
    parser m_parser;
    m_parser.test();
    return 0;
}
```

**uart.h**

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//extern uint16_t buffer_size;
//extern char buffer[1024];

class uart
{
public:
    // Construction
    uart();

    //..... some functions
    void Initialize();

    //members
    enum STATE_enum
    {
        Buffering_message=0,
        Message_received,
        Buffering_empty
    };
    STATE_enum state;

    uint16_t buffer_size;
    char buffer[1024];
protected:
    //  static void UARTHandler(app_uart_evt_t * p_event);
    void Message();
    // Singleton instance
    static uart * m_instance;
};
```

**uart.cpp**

```
#include "uart.h"
//uint16_t buffer_size=0;
//char buffer[1024];

uart * uart::m_instance = 0; // Singleton instance

uart::uart()// Construction
{
    state = Buffering_empty;
    m_instance = this;
}

void uart::Initialize()
{
}
/*void UART::UARTHandler(app_uart_evt_t * p_event)
{
    Message();
}*/
void uart::Message()
{
    uint8_t value;
//  while ((app_uart_get(&value)) == NRF_SUCCESS) //specific function from my microcontroller stack for reading RX bytes
    {
        if(value == 0x0A ) // message end /r
            state = Message_received;
    }       
    switch (state)
    {
        case Message_received:
                printf("message:[%s] buffer_size:[%d]", buffer,buffer_size); //printf fine from there
        break;      
        case Buffering_message:
                buffer[buffer_size++] = value;              
        break;
        default:
        break;      
    }       
}
```

**parser.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "uart.h"

class parser : public uart
{
public: 
    parser();

    void test();
    static parser * m_instance; 

    static inline parser & Instance()// Singleton access
    {
        return *m_instance;
    }       
};
```

**parser.cpp**

```
#include "parser.h"

class parser * parser::m_instance = 0;

// Constructor
parser::parser()
{
    m_instance = this;
}

void parser::test()
{       
    printf("state %s", state); // sending AT command

//  memset(buffer, 0, buffer_size); 
//  buffer_size = 0;    
}
```

Should I use the above as a Public class or add it as a friend class, or simply use as external variables?

Comment: Off-topic: don't implement singleton pattern *and* provide public constructor(s)! Better variant (guaranteed by standard even to be threadsafe): `SC& instance() { static SC sc; return sc; }`

Comment: Where did you _try_ using those members? I can't see any code in `parser` that does. What error message did you get?

Comment: When you say, "I can't use members variables in parser class", what does that mean *exactly* ? Does the compiler fail to ingest your code ? Is there some error when you *run* the code after successful compile? Fwiw, that's not a proper singleton pattern (if there even is such a thing), but somehow I don't think that's related to whatever problem you're *really* having. Even if this compiles `buffer_size` is indeterminate, so that `memset` call is a recipe for a runtime fault.

Comment: As `parser` inherits from `uart`, creating a `parser` object will end up in both singletons point to the same instance, losing a possibly previously created separate `uart` singleton object! Is this what you intended?

Comment: @Aconcagua, yes, that is my goal

Comment: @Useless, I said I cant use the variable members, becuase they are not updating or changing their values on my formal code

Comment: Do you rely on `parser` being a `uart`? Class names rather imply that they adhere to orthogonal concepts. Maybe better not inheriting and let `parser` get and use the `uart` singleton?

Comment: I  just want to use the members variables from **uart**, inside the  **parser**, but I am not sure the correct way to do it, for me the simpler way is using extern variables, but it probably is not the proper way when we are using singleton

Comment: Don't really get the issue... `void parser::f() { state = BufferingEmpty; }` is fine... Only if you have a separate `state` variable within parser, you'd need for accessing the base class instance: `uart::state = BufferingEmpty;`.

Comment: From the little bit of code you provided, I'd assume the singleton is just not needed, so you might prefer just to drop it. *If* you still decide you need it, implement it correctly. Current design is flawed and at some point in future, you're bound to *fail*, either already in current project or in a future one, if you transfer the design as is...

Comment: when I tried to printf: **void parser::test(){ printf("state %s", state);** I got nothing or if I try to printf any variable member from uart, it returns null it is not updating with changes to the variables on uart.cpp

Comment: @Meliodas `state` is not a C string!!! `%s` only is for C strings (i. e. null terminated character arrays). Try `printf("state %u", (unsigned int)state);` instead.

Comment: It was just too easy to overlook the `%s` problem because your example is not minimal. Have a look at [mcve]. You should remove all parts that are not relevant for the error. Iterative steps: remove part of code, test if problem persists, if so, go on, else keep the code part just removed. You might start with entire classes, when done, functions of the classes that remained, finally function blocks... During this process, chances are that you already discover the problem yourself (most likely, though, not in given case...).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see any useful way to answer this question without code that actually demonstrates the problem. The suggestion to reduce it to a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is correct - code that isn't required to reproduce the issue just makes it harder to read, but the code really _does_ need to demonstrate the problem you're asking about. Right now I still don't know if you're not sure what to write in the first place, or have a compile error, or it builds but gives unexpected results at runtime.

Comment: Back to dropping singletons: Even if you do so, I still recommend `parser` not letting inherit from `uart`, instead rather have an aggregated object: `class parser { uart m_uart;; };`. Access is: `void parser::f() { m_uart.state = ...; }`. Consider correct encapsulation, though, providing getters and setters only to what other objects *really* should be able to access (so e. g. the buffer might be private).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial problem apparently was using a bad format specifier:

```
void parser::test()
{       
    printf("state %s", state);
    //            ^^
}
```

`%s` is for C strings only (i. e. null terminated `char` arrays). Here, `state` is interpreted as a pointer, but it points to invalid addresses (undefined behaviour), so you're application might have crashed before it was able to produce any output at all.

Even if `state` *did* contain a valid address, you would still suffer from undefined behaviour because `%s` requires an argument of type `char*` (to avoid UB, you need to cast).

Use the correct format specifier to get around the problem:

```
printf("state %u", static_cast<unsigned int>(state));
```

You still need the cast to avoid UB as `%u` requires `unsigned int`, but your enum is not (alternatively you could use `%d` and cast to `int`).

Apparently, too, you now tried (because of not having discovered the actual error) to get around what you *assumed* it to be by use of singletons – unfortunaly, by badly implementing the pattern, you flawed your design.

How to repair? At first, drop the singletons. There absolutely is no need for in given case. Then think twice (the following already was an issue *before*): Is a parser really an UART? Not considering the code, but the concepts, I clearly say "no". So you should not let *inherit* `parser` from `uart` either. Rather let it aggregate one:

```
class parser // : public uart
{
    uart m_uart;
public:
    // ...
    void test()
    {
        printf("%u", static_cast<unsigned int>(m_uart.state);
    }
```

};

Alternatively, you might provide it externally via pointer or reference (to the constructor) and store it as such, but then you will quickly run into life time management as well, more advanced concepts I'd recommend you to come back to with a little bit more of experience...

What you *should* get used to, though: encapsulation. Don't make member variables public unless you *really* want them to be changed from *anywhere*. For instance, the `buffer` is a hot candidate for being private (not even protected).

Finally `buffer_size`: If you intend this to be used to count number of values *currently* in buffer, then it is fine. If it shall represent the maximum number of data that *can* be stored, then it is redundant. Wherever you need it, you can get the size by `sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(*buffer)` (unless the array has decayed to pointer!). Division by size of first element is necessary as `sizeof` always delivers size in bytes, *not* in number of elements.

Size in number of elements is what you get by `std::array::size`; you should prefer [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) over raw arrays due to the superior interface! Maybe [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) even is a yet better choice?

Comment: dude thanks for your help, I absolutely should learn a lot more about programming patterns, I am just using singleton because some code I am working on uses it. I am new in c++ world so I don't have enough experience yet